# Last entered HashMap key is setting for every element in the map

Tags: java, android, xml, hashmap

I'm using XMLPullParser to parse my XML into a hashmap. My XML is a "menu" and the hashmap's key is the category and the value is an ArrayList of menu items. But, in the HashMap, the last key entered is the key for ALL of the items in the HashMap, not just the last element. Why is this? Here is my code:

```
   public HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> getMenu() throws IOException,
        XmlPullParserException {

    XmlPullParser xpp = appContext.getResources().getXml(R.xml.menu);

    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> menuItems = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    String catName = null;
    while (xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if (xpp.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            if (xpp.getName().equals("categoryname")) {
                catName = xpp.nextText();
                menuItems = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
            } else if (xpp.getName().equals("item")) {
                items.add(xpp.nextText());
            }
        } else if (xpp.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if (xpp.getName().equals("category")) {
                System.out.println("Adding Category: " + catName);
                menuItems.put(catName, items);
                catName = new String();
            }
        }

        xpp.next();
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : menuItems.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        ArrayList<String> value = entry.getValue();
        for(String str : value) {
            System.out.println("Category: " + key + " Item: " + str);
        }
    }

    return menuItems;
}
```

and the XML I am parsing looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<restaurant>
   <restaurantname>Arbys</restaurantname>
   <category>
      <categoryname>Roast Beef Sanwiches</categoryname>
      <item>Sandwich</item>
      <item>Melt</item>
   </category>
   <category>
      <categoryname>Beverages</categoryname>
      <item>Brewed Iced Tea</item>
   </category>
   <category>
      <categoryname>Breakfast</categoryname>
      <item>Bacon, Egg &amp; Cheese Biscuit</item>
      <item>Chicken Biscuit</item>
   </category>
   <category>
      <categoryname>Chicken</categoryname>
      <item>Crispy Chicken Sandwich</item>
      <item>Prime-Cut Chicken Tenders</item>
   </category>
</restaurant>
```

and my log looks like this:

```
System.out(7153): Adding Category: Roast Beef Sanwiches
System.out(7153): Adding Category: Beverages
System.out(7153): Adding Category: Breakfast
System.out(7153): Adding Category: Chicken
System.out(6523): Category: Chicken Item: Sandwich
System.out(6523): Category: Chicken Item: Melt
System.out(6523): Category: Chicken Item: Brewed Iced Tea
System.out(6523): Category: Chicken Item: Bacon, Egg & Cheese Biscuit
System.out(6523): Category: Chicken Item: Chicken Biscuit
System.out(6523): Category: Chicken Item: Crispy Chicken Sandwich
System.out(6523): Category: Chicken Item: Prime-Cut Chicken Tenders
```

So, 'Chicken' is the category for them all, however, it should only be the category for the last 2 items. Anyone know what's up? Thanks

Comment: Please note that `HashMap`s are not ordered in any sense.

Comment: I'm not implying they are, ordered or not, the last key entered is the key for all my items, not just the last

Comment: @MickMnemonic that's not the problem he has though.

Comment: Where are your logs for `Adding Category`?

Comment: This row within the loop looks suspect to me: `menuItems = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();`

Comment: @user1282637 if you add logs into the "item" path - how does it log? Are they in order?

Comment: @MickMnemonic AH! that is supposed to be for the ArrayList, not the HashMap...I'm so dumb

Comment: Yes, you might have been re-creating the map for each XML start tag.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Yeah, that was it, got it working now. Such a simple mistake, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of two things: the loop keeps creating new objects for `menuitems` every time a tag called `categoryname` is found and all of the items keep getting added to the same `items` list. So in the end you have a single `menuitems` map which was created the last category found and it is adding all items since they were all added to the same list.